# Delphi: paint column of list view

Tags: delphi, listview

I draw a list view with `OwnerDraw`. I need to paint the first column. But I cannot understand how.

I tried:

```
procedure TFrame6.DownloadListCustomDraw(Sender: TCustomListView;
  const ARect: TRect; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
    var
      R: TRect;
    begin                  
      DefaultDraw := False;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := $F7F7F7;
      Sender.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
      R := ARect;
      R.Right := ListView_GetColumnWidth(DownloadList.Handle, DownloadList.Columns[0].Index);
      Sender.Canvas.FillRect(R);  
      DefaultDraw := True;
    end;
```

But I draw over items. How to draw correctly, items and a background?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you to read [this delphiDabbler article](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16) and hope that it contains enough information to resolve your problem. I post a comment rather than answer because it's googled in 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks! I've read that. "The OnCustomDrawXXX event handlers of Delphi's TListView can be useful to make minor changes to the appearance of a list view control. They let developers avoid having to owner draw the control if they only want to make a few tweaks to its appearance." I use OwnerDraw.

Comment: Please, scroll over entire page and look for examples. I think you can find one that satisfies your needs. E.g. [Example 1](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16&part=1#eg1) shows how to change background and [Example 4](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16&part=1#eg4) shows point where item appearance can be changed.

Comment: Small tip: don't restore DefaultDraw to True at the end of the handler if you don't want text to be drawn.

Comment: @ThinkJet, please answer, I'll accept

Comment: Ok, it's done - answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary from comments:

I suggest you to read [this delphiDabbler article](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16) and hope that it contains enough information to resolve your problem. E.g. [Example 1](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16&part=1#eg1) shows how to change background and [Example 4](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16&part=1#eg4) shows point where item appearance can be changed.

Small tip: don't restore DefaultDraw to True at the end of the handler if you don't want text to be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use VirtualStringTree if you want a lot of customization on the list. Its easy to use and almost anything is possible and most of all freeware. The component can be downloaded at [Soft-Gems](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38) and few example can be found [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/VirtualTreeview_Example_for_Lazarus)

Comment: @maxfax, VirtualStringTree is more capable to customize than a ListView or TreeView. Look at the examples and see. Many of the dialogs in the Delphi IDE are based on this component.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm asking about a List View. But I posted an event from a Tree View when I edited a code. So now an event is right.